# Magento 2 Redirect shopping cart link on message notification in iframe

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, magento2.2.6, redirect-url

I can not redirect to the shopping cart link outside the iframe.
It still redirect but it stays in the iframe. magento 2.2.6
when i click shopping cart 
[image]

result : 
[image]

I want it redirect to shopping cart but not in iframe.
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can manage the iframe content, you should change the link redirection and manage the parent location with it.

The way to do it is: 
window.top.location.href = "/your-url-link-redirect";

Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue while I was working.
I checked and found that there is template file for displaying message for product is added successfully.

**Message is:**

```
You added PRODUCT_NAME to your shopping cart.
```

**File: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/messages/addCartSuccessMessage.phtml**

I have checked code it's as below:

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml(__(
    'You added %1 to your <a href="%2">shopping cart</a>.',
    $block->getData('product_name'),
    $block->getData('cart_url')
), ['a']);
```

I have copied that file into custom theme:

**app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME_NAME/Magento_Checkout/templates/messages/addCartSuccessMessage.phtml**

Changed code as below:

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml(__(
    'You added %1 to your <a href="%2" target="_top">shopping cart</a>.',
    $block->getData('product_name'),
    $block->getData('cart_url')
), ['a']);
```

After that I have checked that it's working as expected.
Clicking on the **shopping cart** link, page redirects to cart page in the browser rather then in the iframe.